# Python - module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, macos, python-requests, homebrew

I'm trying to use `requests` in Python 3 on MacOS and getting

```
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'
```

Python is installed with brew, and so is requests - I did `brew install python-requests`

My script starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python3` which pulls in Python 3.12 from brew.

My script is **not** named requests.py and there is no requests.py anywhere as far as I can tell.

This looks puzzling:

```
% /usr/bin/env python3
Python 3.12.2 (main, Feb  6 2024, 20:19:44) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://google.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'
>>> print("requests file:", requests.__file__)
requests file: None
>>>
```

Comment: If you create a virtualenv and `pip install requests` there, do you get the same problem?

Comment: one way to debug what module gets loaded: run `python3 -v -c "import requests"`

Comment: also: check your sys.path

Comment: `requests.__file__ == None` is what you get when you import a package lacking any `.py` files (even `__init__.py`). You may have installed `python-requests`, but you did not import the actual `requests` module.

Comment: Even ignoring https://justinmayer.com/posts/homebrew-python-is-not-for-you/, I would be installing any packages using `pip`, not `brew`.

Comment: My guess: `brew install python-requests` created an empty directory named `requests` in your search path and didn't populate it. How or why, I don't know and wouldn't be terribly interested in finding out. Install `requests` with `pip`, not `brew`.

Comment: Issue is not an installation problem, but a supportability one. If you use cutting edge tech, you will bleed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue...

I reinstalled the package with:

```
brew reinstall python-requests
```

And an error appears that the target was already there.

So I run afterwards:

```
brew link --overwrite python-requests
```

I had to repeat this for a lot of python packages.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. Its a way to try to fix it, but its a support issue, not an installation process issue

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the official requests [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) as of 03/01/24, python 12.x is not supported. Python 3.7-3.11 is. My recommendation would be to drop to python 3.11.